# GETTING LAUNCHER2 SOURCE CODE?

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to get the launcher2 source code, but it says use repo and git.

Does anyone know what to do to do this?

i have tried multiple times!

--

Or if any one has the actual source code i can download from that would also be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3

And instructions on how to download it are at http://source.android.com

Comment: @Romain Guy : provided link is no longer working .http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/master;hb=refs/heads/master

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+archive/88cf19181afeb76c5c1444703ee402bf827238d9.tar.gz

Its recent updated source code of 4.3 and you can find out all open source project of android from https://android.googlesource.com